# In C# windows forms how can I use TextBox.Text as another property name to display text on a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, textbox

In C# windows forms how can I use TextBox.**Text** property as another property named TextBox.**WritePublicText** to display text on a multiline textbox? I am editing C# game code that cannot be modified. I am trying to simulate the game code exactly in Visual Studio to edit and then copy directly into the game code. Also I am new to C# so try to dumb it down.

This code displays the text on the windows form textbox named textBox1:

```
textBox1.Text = "Text to display\r\n"
                + "More Text\r\n"
                + "More Text2\r\n";
```

This is the code displays the text in game. But I cannot figure out how make it display the text in a windows form textbox.

```
textBox1.WritePublicText = "Text to display\r\n"
                + "More Text\r\n"
                + "More Text2\r\n";
```

Other Ideas:

It might be possible to display multiline text another way on windows forms that will allow me to do this.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do? You seem to have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Making a new property that does exactly the same thing as an existing one does not sound useful at all. Please explain your broader goal here. Provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what your code does, and explain precisely what you want it to do instead and what _specific_ issue you are having accomplishing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class and inherit from Windows.Forms.TextBox.

Like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public String WritePublicText
        {
            get { return Text; }
            set { Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

This tool now is exactly like a normal TextBox, but now it contais a new method called "WritePublicText" that sets and returns a String.

Rebuild your application, then you will see a new tool in your toolBox called CustomTextBox, just drag and drop like any other component.

If you already have to many TextBoxes in you application you could go in your designer file and change the 'TextBox' to 'CustomTextBox' and then rebuild again.

Comment: Thanks John this is exactly what i was looking for. I appreciate your time. I tried to figure this out on my own for about 10 hours. I am new to the C# language. Thank your for the complete code and how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Write a subclass of `TextBox` which has a public property like so:

```
public String WritePublicText {
    get { return Text; }
    set { Text = value; }
}
```

And use that control instead of `TextBox` in your UI.

You'll probably have to add a constructor as well to get it to work with the form designer in Visual Studio. Look at the `Form1.Designer.cs` file in your project (assuming the Form is named `Form1`; use common sense) to see how the current TextBox is being created; that's the constructor you'll need to duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you let use *method* instead of *property* (moreover `Write...` being an *verb* sounds as a *method* and doesn't look like a *property's name*) you can implement extension method:

```
public static class TextBoxExtensions {
  public static void WritePublicText(this TextBox textBox, string value) {
    if (null == textBox)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");

    textBox.Text = value;
  }
}
```

...

```
// Extension method instead of property
textBox1.WritePublicText(
    "Text to display\r\n"
  + "More Text\r\n"
  + "More Text2\r\n");
```